# Is there a way to display HTML5 required pop-up when hiding the input?

Tags: css, html

I have a checkbox that I am styling by hiding the input and targetting a span nested in a label. See http://jsfiddle.net/rz6np/

HTML:

```
<input id="confirm" type="checkbox" name="confirm" value="1" required="required" />
<label for="confirm"><span>+</span>Confirm</label>
```

CSS:

```
    input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

form input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 1px 10px 5px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    color: #000;
}
```

As the input is hidden it means the html5 `required` pop-up doesn't display. Is there a way to force it to display?

Comment: No.  What good would telling the user that the field is invalid be if the user cannot see it?  The pop-up is part of the input element itself.

Comment: @cimmanon I have hidden the input so I could style the checkbox

Comment: So don't style it?  The browser has no idea that you're hiding it for "styling" purposes, it only knows that its inaccessible to the user because it is hidden.

Comment: @cimmanon if it was my project I wouldn't but this is for a client's design :\

Comment: You can "hide" the checkbox without actually making it hidden.  For example, jquery-ui does this with checkboxes via something like `width: 1; height: 1; clip: rect(0 0 0 0)`.  I don't know how this would affect the popup, however.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the design looks like this or similar to this, don't use display: none. The styled checkbox is large enough to cover it, so just position it over the checkbox with position relative or absolute, and appropriate z-index.

If it won't cover it completely, you could still get away with using visibility:hidden on the checkbox. I still see the popup in Firefox even though the field is invisible, but you'll need to check other browsers and how they behave.

Answer (score 0):

input and span should be inside the label:

```
<label for="confirm">
   <input id="confirm" type="checkbox" name="confirm" value="1" required="required" />
   <span>+</span>
   Confirm
</label>
```

Then on input:

```
label {
   position: relative;
}

label > input[type="checkbox"] {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```